# RCurl Installation in R 3.1.1: package 'RCurl' is not available (for R version 3.1.1)?

Tags: r, installation, debian

It says in [Cran](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RCurl/index.html) that RCurl should be for R >3.0.0 but R 3.1.1 in Debian Jessie fires the error:

```
package 'RCurl' is not available (for R version 3)
```

the same problem with rjson. The dependencies are libcurl and make that are installed. What is the problem with R 3.1.1 in installing the libcurl packages such as RCurl? How to overcome this the most convenient way?

*P.s. I know this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25721884/how-should-i-deal-with-package-xxx-is-not-available-for-r-version-x-y-z-wa) but any method did not solve this issue.*

Comment: R binary packages are built for the latest version of R as well as some number of maintenance versions (2.15.3, 3.0.3, 3.1.3, 3.2.5). Since 3.1.1 is not in this set, binary CRAN packages are not available. You might search through MS's archive repositories. Here is [a link](https://mran.revolutionanalytics.com/snapshot/2014-10-31/) to the most recent vesion that will work for 3.1.1. Note that this is from October 2014.

Answer (score 0):

Apt-get install the 3.1.1 R version by default, for example in Debian Jessie. We can either install the newest version of R with the newest RCurl or install the archived version of RCurl working in R 3.1.1.

**Solution A**

You can install the newest version, [source](http://vinhqdang.github.io/tutorial/2016/04/19/installing-latest-r325-on-debian-jessie), such that

```
sudo sh -c 'echo "deb http://cran.rstudio.com/bin/linux/debian jessie-cran3/" >> /etc/apt/sources.list'

sudo apt-key adv --keyserver subkeys.pgp.net --recv-key 381BA480

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install r-base r-base-dev
```

and now you can install RCurl in R, working in R 3.3.2.

**Solution B**

Install the Curl from the CRAN Archieves matching the 3.1.1 R, apparently this [here](https://mran.revolutionanalytics.com/snapshot/2014-10-31/) as suggested by Imo in the comment.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with R:

```
R version 4.2.3 (2023-03-15)
```

In Ubuntu 22.04. The package simply could not be installed from inside R.

This worked (as root):

```
apt install r-cran-rcurl
```

After this, I could install `Ecdat` from inside R, which has `RCurl` as a dependency.